Bash script for adding two leading zeros in the middle of the file names
I have the files with two numbers in the middle of each file:
FileName_46_01.wav
FileName_6_15.wav
FileName_3_7.wav
FileName_15_22.wav

and so on.
I need to rename files with shell script to add the leading zeros if it's needed:
FileName_46_01.wav
FileName_06_15.wav
FileName_03_07.wav
FileName_15_22.wav


What have you tried so far?

Like this, using Perl's rename command:
rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf "%.2d", $&/ge' ./*.wav

Remove -n if happy with the output (dry-run mode).
